# How to add one item to the top of a redux store list while removing the bottom item from the list

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to remove only one item from a redux store list, once it has reached a certain number and return the new store with the new value added, but minus the first value on the list (array.shift).

Think of a twitter stream that fills the store so every six tweets we are removing one from the bottom of the list and adding a new one to the top.

code:

```
// ------------------------------------
// Action Handlers
// ------------------------------------
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [INIT_DATA]: (state, action) => {
    if (state.length < 5) {
      return [ ...state, action.payload.stream ]
    } else {
      return [ ...state.shift(), action.payload.stream ]
    }
  },
  [DISCONNECT]: (state, action) => ({ ...state, ...action.payload })
}
// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
const initialState = []

export default function twitterStreamReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]

  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}
```

The above code returns a new store when lentgh > 5 and deletes all the old tweets not just the bottom one.

Any ideas on the best way to do it without  mutating the state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Array.slice which returns a shallow copy of your original array minus the sliced items. DO NOT use shift() which actually mutates your state and can cause all sorts of issues.

```
return [...state.slice(1), action.payload.stream]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) returns the shifted value, not the array with the value removed (it shifts it in-place).

You can do

```
state.shift()
[ ...state, action.payload.steam ]
```

although I'm pretty sure Redux docs specify that you should avoid acting on the state directly...